# Add Collection to meteor.js project

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, collections, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to add a Collection to my Meteor.js. I used a template from meteorkitchen and added some code:

In my home.js file (subfolder in client folder) I have this code:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');

Template.HomeSection2Content2.helpers({
    tasks: function() {
        return Tasks.find();    
    }
});
```

I know that my home.html file works, because if if replace the code in the TemplateHelper with:

```
Template.HomeSection2Content2.helpers({
tasks: [
{ text: 'This is task 1' },
{ text: 'This is task 2' },
{ text: 'This is task 3' },
  ],
});
```

everything works correctly.

I also added

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
```

to my server.js file.

When i try to add something through my MongoDB Shell to this collection, nothing happens to the FrontEnd.
I don't get an error message

Comment: are you publishing that collection on the server? is that template/route subscribing to the publication?

Comment: sorry completely beginner, how do I publish a collection?

Comment: [Meteor's Guide on Publications](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html) should get you started. You're making the right calls on the client, but without publishing any data the client cannot request it.

Comment: I tried also to use this simple [Tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/collections) to connect the mongoDB through a Collection to my Application. Here it looks very simple, why do I need a Publication in my code and in the example it works without?

Comment: Data is still being published behind the scenes through the `autopublish` package. That means that your entire database is being published on the server, and subscribed to on the client. Once you remove that package, you  must manually set up all pub/sub calls.

Comment: Read the first paragraph of the [publication and subscription](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe) section of that tutorial, you will see this explained in detail.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. Now everything is clear! You made my day ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Data is still being published behind the scenes through the autopublish package. That means that your entire database is being published on the server, and subscribed to on the client. Once you remove that package, you must manually set up all pub/sub calls

Problem solved!